# getDownloadURL not getting all urls

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm uploading three photos to my firebase storage, when I try to retrieve the firebase URL of each image with getDownloadURL, it only returns two objects instead of three

```
        //const uploadedFilesURL = [];
        uploadToStorage.map((image) => {
            const storageRef = ref(storage, `images/${image.name + v4()}`);
            uploadBytes(storageRef, image).then((snapshot) => {
                getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref).then((url) => {
                    //console.log(image);
                    //console.log(url);
                    uploadedFilesURL.push({file: image, url})
                })
            });
        });

        console.log(uploadedFilesURL);
```

However, when I console.log the image and URL, I get the three objects (which is what I need, but i don't want to console the image)

```
        const uploadedFilesURL = [];
        uploadToStorage.map((image) => {
            const storageRef = ref(storage, `images/${image.name + v4()}`);
            uploadBytes(storageRef, image).then((snapshot) => {
                getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref).then((url) => {
                    console.log(image);
                    console.log(url);
                    uploadedFilesURL.push({file: image, url})
                })
            });
        });

        console.log(uploadedFilesURL);
```

I'm trying to get the firebase URL path so I can store it in a separate database as a reference, which is why I'm creating an object called uploadedFilesURL.

Thanks!

Comment: Your `map` is completing before all the async work is complete.  Calling `then` on a promise doesn't block the progress of the iteration.  You need to wait for all the promises to fully resolve before using `uploadedFilesURL` with its final contents, and `map` isn't a very good way of doing that since it doesn't know anything about promises. (Also map doesn't make sense to use at all here since you're ignoring its return value.) Instead, try collecting all the promises into an array and use `Promise.all` to do something when they're all complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Doug commented, your code fails to wait for all uploads and calls to `getDownloadURL` to complete before logging the results. The simplest way to fix this is to use `Promise.all`:

```
let promises = uploadToStorage.map((image) =>
  const storageRef = ref(storage, `images/${image.name + v4()}`);
  return uploadBytes(storageRef, image).then((snapshot) => {
    return getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref);
  })
);

Promise.all(promises).then((urls) => {
  console.log(urls);
});
```

Or alternatively (if you're in an `async` context) for that last part:

```
const urls = await Promise.all(promises);
console.log(urls);
```